# android:External apps crash when trying to set Wallpaper

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app which in turn let user to set the image as wallpaper. I am downing the image via picasso and saving it into internal storage.File is getting saved and I am creating file:// URI for intent to share to other apps (gallery app for setting it as wallpaper). But the problem is when I select the app I want to set wallpaper by crashes. (both in built gallery and whatsapp also). I tried to log the image file path and created file:// URI path, they look different which is normal I think. But why the other app sharing the pic is crashing though image is saved into the sd card.Aren't the images from my app accesible for other apps? If not what to do to make them accessible?

Below is my code where I am tryig to set it as wallpaper and below are the logs of the File image path and URI path.

```
public void setWallpaper(){

        if(imageFile !=null){
            Log.d("FILE",imageFile);
            File file=new File(imageFile);
            Uri apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    WallpaperDetailActivity.this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

            Log.d("ANURAN",apkURI.getPath()+"");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkURI, "image/jpeg");
            intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Set As: "),100);
        }

    }
```

//Logs

```
02-05 00:00:07.306 2303-3242/com.mranuran.animewallpapershd I/image: image saved to >>>/storage/emulated/0/AnimeWallpapersHD/758665.jpg
    02-05 00:00:13.476 2303-2303/com.mranuran.animewallpapershd D/FILE: /storage/emulated/0/AnimeWallpapersHD/758665.jpg
    02-05 00:00:13.478 2303-2303/com.mranuran.animewallpapershd D/ANURAN: /external_files/AnimeWallpapersHD/758665.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some thorough reading in Android Doc, it seems even after providing File URI I had to add a flag to the intent to make it readable by other apps.
So I had to just one line and it is working fine now.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using general Uri by `Uri.fromFile(file)` in setDataAndType method of intent.

So final code will be,

```
public void setWallpaper(){

    if(imageFile !=null){
        Log.d("FILE",imageFile);
        File file =new File(imageFile);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Set As: "),100);
    }

}
```

Comment: General URI won't work, I have started this with that only.You have to use file:// (content) URI.

Comment: Weird, I just quickly tried on my device to confirm if it works and it did.

Comment: may be your target SDK is lower. I am targetting 23+

Comment: No, I'm targeting 8.0. These are my gradle config - `compileSdkVersion 26
 minSdkVersion 16
 targetSdkVersion 26` .